# How do I get GCC to put a char in ah/bh/ch/dh?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

Suppose I have some inline assembly that needs a particular `char` value in `ah`, `bh`, `ch`, or `dh`. How can I tell GCC to put it there? I don't see a relevant constraint to do that, but the GCC manual says "If you must use a specific register, but your Machine Constraints do not provide sufficient control to select the specific register you want, local register variables may provide a solution", so I tried that:

```c
void f(char x) {
    register char y __asm__("ah") = x;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "# my value ended up in %0" :: "a"(y)
    );
}
```

But it didn't work. It put it in `al` instead:

```
        movb    4(%esp), %al
        # my value ended up in %al
```

The x86-specific `Q` constraint also looks close to what I want, so I tried it in place of `a`, but it had the same result. I also tried with the more-generic `r`.

Interestingly, when I compile with Clang instead of GCC (whether with `a`, `Q`, or `r`), then I do get the desired result:

```
        movb    4(%esp), %ah
        # my value ended up in %ah
```

I also tried with `bh`, `ch`, and `dh` in place of `ah`, and every combination of them led to analogous results.

I also tried compiling as 64-bit instead of 32-bit. There, GCC still does basically the same wrong thing:

```
        movl    %edi, %eax
        # my value ended up in %al
```

And Clang utterly failed to compile with `Cannot encode high byte register in REX-prefixed instruction` unless I turned off optimizations (which I opened [LLVM issue #45210](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/45210) about), in which case it did eventually get the value in the right place:

```
        movb    %dil, -1(%rsp)
        movb    -1(%rsp), %al
        movb    %al, -2(%rsp)
        movb    -2(%rsp), %ah
        # my value ended up in %ah
```

Is this a bug in GCC that I should report, or is this something that's not supposed to work and is only working by chance in Clang? If the latter, is there  a way to do what I want, or will I have to settle for `mov`ing it there from somewhere else myself from within the assembly?

[32-bit Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/FaF0df). [64-bit Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/7Y_v_b).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"r"(y)`?

Comment: Anyway; I had the same problem on ia16-gcc.  Never managed to find a way.

Comment: @fuz Maybe, but that doesn't change anything (still works on Clang but not on GCC).

Comment: What's worse is if you have both `ah` and `al` ... gcc silently ignores one of them.

Comment: If you ask for `(int)y<<8` in EAX, you can use `%h0` and `%b0` in the template to expand to AH and AL.  (Or BH and BL if GCC picked EBX).  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86-Operand-Modifiers.  A `"Q"` constraint makes sure the `%h0` modifier can work by picking one of E[ABCD]X.  That's why the Q constraint exists, not get GCC to actually *pick* AH on it own.  I'd have hoped it would be compatible with a `register char foo asm("ah");` but that is a separate thing.

Comment: re: clang: with optimization enabled I assume it was trying to emit `mov %dil, %ah` which is not encodeable.  (DIL needs a REX; AH is only encodeable without a REX).  Any ICE could be considered a bug, but the bugfix might just be a better warning when a `register asm` variable provokes it, or making clang work like GCC and picking AL instead of AH!  Or possibly emitting `rorx $24, %edx, %eax` to get DIL into AH in one BMI2 instruction while avoiding the REX problem.

Comment: Have you tried padding the 8-bit value into a 32-bit value then putting it into "a"?

Comment: This is totally off in another direction, but I'm curious what was compelling you to put something in AH. I can think of a use case but that is related to 16-bit real mode. Although because of bug/deficiency you can't load AH directly with a constraint on GCC as of yet you can always move something into AH inside the inline assembly. Or simply use EAX and store `(int)y<<8` as peter mentioned. What you are asking is doable, but not directly (efficiently) as you'd like. Places I have had to deal with this issue is in using inline assembly to make BIOS calls.

Comment: The `"a"` constraint specifies al/ax/eax/rax (depending on size), so its not suprising it puts it there.  Try the `"r"` constraint to allow a different register.

Comment: @ChrisDodd "I also tried with the more-generic `r`."

Comment: At one point I bumped into the fact that you can use numbers for the register name.  For example `register char x asm("43");` ends up using `r15b`.  No, I don't know how the numbers are mapped to names.  Logically it seems like something in [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/i386/i386.h;h=47340c6a4adfe63f57862c84169bab63c32a4152;hb=refs/heads/trunk) should tell you, but I'm not seeing it. No guarantees that there's a number that works for ah, but it might be something to try.

Comment: And while you've probably already considered it, there's also: `void f(unsigned char al, unsigned char ah) { register unsigned short y __asm__("ax") = al | (ah << 8);  __asm__ __volatile__("# my value ended up in %0" :: "a"(y)); }`.  Not as sexy as being able to specify "al" and "ah" directly, but possibly about as efficient.  Optimizers are really smart, and they may be able to roll that `<<` and `|` into previous operations.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, constraints don't allow selecting the nested registers, but you can add an `h` modifier to instruction references. This is mentioned in the docs on [Input Operands](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands). For example,

```c
void f(char x) {
    char a;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "mov  %0, %h1" :: "X"(x), "a"(a)
    );
}
```

produces

```
f:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        mov  4(%esp), %ah
        ret
```

I haven't been able to get rid of the `xor` that clears `eax`. My guess is the code generator is interpreting "%h1" as a 32-bit word with 8 bits set, not a character register reference.  For example, this:

```
char f(char x) {
    char a;
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "movb  %0, %h1" :: "X"(x), "a"(a)
    );
    return a;
}
```

... compiles to the same code, even though it returns `\0`, not very intuitive.

Comment: Your second C snippet looks like straight-up Undefined Behavior, since it's returning `a` without having ever set it.

Comment: Your examples don't quite make sense because you have got both registers as input operands.  But anyway, the register modifier causes the generated assembly to refer to `%ah`, but the compiler still doesn't know that, and will try to load the input value into `%al` instead.  You can't see that in your example because you didn't initialize `a`.  But if you do initialize it, as in [this example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/), you see that the resulting code is not what you want.

Comment: In other words, I think `%h1` is completely opaque to the code generator.  The compiler generates the surrounding code as if you had just written plain `%1`, and then just changes the name of the register in your assembly.  So this really doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I think the register modifier feature is meant for a situation when you have a value loaded into a 32-bit register but your assembly only wants to operate on part of it. For instance `unsigned a=..., x; asm("movb $0x5a,  %h0" : "=Q" (x) : "0" (a))` would be a valid way to achieve `x = a & 0xffff00ff | 0x5a00` in one instruction.

Comment: @NateEldredge The mov instruction sets `a`.

Comment: @Gene No it doesn't. `a` is only marked as an input by your constraints, not an output, so GCC doesn't care what change you make to its register in the assembly.

Comment: "only marked as an input" and "GCC doesn't care what change you make to its register." I don't believe that's true.  The [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands) have a big WARNING: *Do not modify the contents of input-only operands* because *The compiler assumes that on exit from the asm statement these operands contain the same values as they had before executing the statement.*